# Change Devices parameter of iOS project programmatically

Tags: ios

I have to make my app run on iPad in iPhone mode(legacy zoomable mode).
**I can do it with changing Devices option in Xcode project settings**, But i released my app in app store in universal device mode so apple says you can't remove this feature in newer version of your app!

Is there any way to do it programmatically? for example **can i set Devices option to iPhone in code at runtime?** or **can i fake it?(made app run like iPhone app in zoomable mode in iPad)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possible way to change an iPad app to iPhone-only at runtime. It would be possible to display your view controllers on an iPad in such a way that they appear the size of an iPhone. But Apple would reject your app for bad user experience.

Once you release an app as Universal, Apple will not let you change the app to iPhone-only. And why would you want to do that? Why would you deliberately want to hurt your customers using iPads?

Your only solution would be to release a brand new app (different bundle id) that is iPhone-only. But then this is bad for all of your existing users (iPhone and iPad).

The proper solution is to embrace your Universal app and properly support iPads.